# Arbitrarily high degree planar covers?

Tags: graph-theory, covering-spaces, planar-graphs

All the graphs I want to discuss are finite, simple, and connected.  A graph $G_1$ *covers* another graph $G_2$ if there is a surjective map $\pi : V(G_1) \to V(G_2)$ that sends edges to edges and such that for any $v \in V(G_2)$ and any preimage $w \in V(G_1)$ with $\pi(w) = v$, the map $\pi$ is a bijection when restricted to the vertices adjacent to $v$, $N(v)$, surjecting $N(w)$.   The degree of $\pi$ is the size of $\pi^{-1}(w)$ for any $w \in V(G_2)$.  Maybe more simply, there is a covering map $G_1 \to G_2$ as topological spaces.

Suppose $G$ is a 3-connected graph.  Can $G$ have connected planar covers of arbitrarily large degree (as covers)? Such graphs would [conjecturally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_cover) embed on the the projective plane.

For a loop graph we sure can -- hence the connectivity assumption.

Comment: Embed your favourite 3-connected (planar) graph into an annulus so that it contains a non-contractible cycle. Now you may multiply the degree arbitrarily, taking $n$-fold covers of the annulus by itself.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov Thank you.